# Partial update in an API

Tags: java, web-services, api

I have a use case in which I need to update some of the fields of an API.
For example:
If API is `UpdateStudentDetails` and the input it takes is:

```
Name
CGPA
Address
Hostel Name
```

Here I want to update `Name` only.
One way is to get all the fields and then update `Name` and call `UpdateStudentDetails` with all the fields. It requires one read call at client side prior to update call.

Other ways are:
1. Ask client what needs to be updated. In this case API signature might look like:

```
     Name
     CGPA
     Address
     Hostel Name
     StudentDetailsToUpdate
```

Here `StudentDetailsToUpdate` is list of enums and enum can have values like `NAME, CGPA, ADDRESS, HOSTEL_NAME`. 
              Based on the enum list provided by client we can update respective fields.

2. Take actions based on field value. So in this case if CGPA is passed as `null` then client does not want to update it and if `Name` is `non-null` then client wants to update.

I am not able to find major pros and cons in above two approaches and seek community’s guidance. I am bit inclined towards first approach as intention is clear for me and I am not taking decisions based on field values as it might be possible that some other language might not have concept of null.

Answer (score 1):

I would go for the second option.

If you go for the first, you'd have to write all this code just for checking what argument needs to be updated.

What would really be a nice option is option 3 :) Use a builder pattern (you can google that easily as it's a widely used pattern). That way you can chain all the values you need to be updated and update them if they aren't null.

You'll get something like

```
UpdateStudentDetails details = new UpdateStudentsBuilder().withName("Tony").withHostelName("Some nice hostel").build();
```